# is there a non unit real matrix satisfied $A^n=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

> If A is a real matrix and $A^{2016}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix , prove that $A$ also is a symmetric positive definite matrix

I wonder if this property is wrong and so I came up with this question :
Is there a non unit real matrix satisfied $A^n=I$ for every $n>1$ ?

Comment: This is very hard to parse. Mind re-wording for clarity?

Comment: Look up involutory matrices.

Comment: @J.M. i think that's the case n=2, what about when n\ge3

Comment: Well, involutory matrices will also resolve the case when the exponent is a power of two. For the more general case: ponder on what it means for the matrix for it to satisfy the characteristic equation $x^n-1=0$.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but I don't see how the two questions are related (one is about symmetric positive matrices, the other is about orthogonal matrices).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli well i think the original question is wrong , so if in my question in the case n=2016 we do have a non unit matrix A , since the n-th root (which by definition is symmetric and positive definite) of symmetric positive definite matrix is uniqueness , the non unit matrix A we have shows that the original question is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not true.

Consider the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\ -1&0 \end{bmatrix}$, where its eigenvalues are $i,-i$. We have that:
$$A^{2016} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1 \end{bmatrix},$$
which is positive definite, but $A$ is not even a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Original:

> is there a non unit real matrix satisfied A^n=I for every n>1 ?

Interpretation:

> For each natural number $n>1$, is there always matrix over the real numbers satisfying $A^n=I$ besides the identity matrix?

For any $n$, you can find a primitive $n$'th root of unity in $\Bbb C$ and then represent it as a matrix in $M_2(\mathbb R)$.

You can do this for larger matrices by just embedding the $2\times 2$ in the upper left hand corner.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation: Does there exist a matrix $A \neq I$ such that for all $n > 1,$ $A^n = I.$  The answer is no, let $A \neq I$ and $A^2 = I.$ Then if $ A(A^2) = A = I,$ we reach a contradiction. Use induction to prove the general result.